# Unable to import module 'UM'

Tags: python, importerror

[image]

System Path is not a problem.
I have been edited pycharm, Visual studio Code.
Compiler is not a problem.
(import os, import sys) is working. However, (from ~ import ~) is not working.
and my module is not importing ...

How can I sole from import error??

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: Sorry sir. this  is my first question. next my question will illustrate a specific problem or that try to solve my problem. Thank you for asking.